# TFS 2015 won't upload custom process template

Tags: tfs-2015

We have a customized version of the Agile template that we've been using since TFS 2013. I have upgraded the template for 2015, which was no big deal. But when I go to upload it I get error "VS402479: You can't overwrite the Agile process template, because it's locked".

I have followed the instructions from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/customize/update-customized-process-template) to upload an updated process template. I have changed the name, description, and minor version strings as described in the documentation.

Here are the values from the metadata node in my ProcessTemplate.xml file:

```
<name>Custom Agile</name>
<description>Custom Template based on MSF Agile</description>
<version type="ADCC42AB-9882-485E-A3ED-7678F01F66BC" major="14" minor="20" />
```

I have tried changing the major version and the minor versions to different, higher increments, and receive the same error.

If I change the type to a different Guid, the template loads just fine. The instructions imply that the Guid should be the same. I'm assuming this is so TFS knows the relationship between the built-in templates and custom templates they are based on.

I have a bunch of team projects to update the features on once the upgrade is complete and do not want to break the relationship to the built-in Agile process template if I can help it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can no longer edit or delete the built in templates in TFS 2015 so you'll have to change the Guid if you want to upload your template.

[Process Template changes to TFS 2015 RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/08/process-template-changes-to-tfs-2015-rtm/)

> In TFS 2015, the system templates are locked and cannot be changed. That change allowed us to overwrite the templates we ship, and with that we were able to rename the templates to Scrum, Agile and CMMI.

To create a custom process template based on a shipped template, simply export an existing template, give it a new name and version, and then reimport it by using the Process Template Manager. Existing projects are unaffected by this change, which means that they can continue to have their process customized by using witadmin.

Comment: "simply export an existing template, *give it a new name and version*, and then reimport it by using the Process Template Manager". Based on the instructions in the question, the Guid needs to remain the same so the system knows which "Category" the process template is related to.

Comment: I take your point that it doesn't specifically call out the guid change but I'm pretty sure that's how it is now to allow them to update the core templates and affect in-flight projects they way it wouldn't in 2013.  You can still update your in-flight projects which are originally created from the MSF Agile 2013 with witadmin but i believe you'll have to change the guid if you want a new custom template to create new projects from.

Comment: After leaving this out here for a few days, and posting on the MSDN forums, I think you're right. Though, it does seem like they originally intended the guid to be the same so they can keep track of the derived templates to keep them up to date with the built-in ones per the roadmap for process template customization in VSO. It will be interesting to see how they're going to solve that with on-premises TFS.

Comment: How do I change the GUID? This answer has been helpful, along with your post on the MSDN forum, but I'm still unclear what I should change the GUID to. Using Tools > Create GUID did not work when I tried to upload the modified template.

Answer (score 0):

We have determined that this issue is not a bug. To upload a custom process template, not only the Process template name needed to change, but the version id also needed to change.

In the `ProcessTemplate.xml` file, find the following settings:

```
<version type="ADCC42AB-9882-485E-A3ED-7678F01F66BC" major="15" minor="10" />.
```

Change `GUID` string to another value. Then try to upload the custom template again.

You can generate a new `Guid` by using this C# code:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

string s = g.ToString();
```